# javascript equivalent of C's nested structures

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

i'm struggling with declaring and accessing data in nested arrays in Javascript

i can easily do it in C using nested structures, declaring first the lowest-level structure and including an array of it when declaring the upper-level structure and so on. I end up with a structure containing an array of structures, each containing an array of structures, etc...

but i have only 3 days of Javascript experience so far...

Just to help you understand how i need the data to be organized, here's an example:

Let's imagine a library, this library has several floors, each floor has the same type of properties (name, number of books...), each floor has several departments and each has the same type of properties, each department has several shelves and so on...

let's say the 1st floor get's its name from some famous mathematician, and is split into two departments: 1/ arithmetics and 2/ geometry

the ideal for me would be to work with the data this way:

```
library.floor[0].name = 'Fermat'

library.floor[0].department[0].name = 'arithmetics'

library.floor[0].department[1].name = 'geometry'

library.floor[0].department[1].shelve[4].authors = // authors list
```

so far i've tried this:

```
var library =

{

floors: [

     {floor_name:'Fermat'},
     {has_a_printing_machine:true},
     {departments:[

        {department_name:'group_theory'},
        {shelves:[

            {shelf_name:'letters_f_z},
            {authors: ["Frobenius","Lagrange"]}]}]}]

};
```

i can get data from:

```
log(library.floors[0].floor_name); // ouputs 'fermat'
log(library.floors[2].departments[0].department_name); // outputs 'group_theory'
log(library.floors[2].departments[1].shelves[1].authors[1]); // outputs 'Lagrange'
```

but it isn't what i need, i can't access a 'departments' property for each floor for instance... and i'd like to add data dynamically in these arrays.

i'm doing it wrong and i can't figure out how to do it right...

thanks for your help!

Comment: *"but it isn't what i need, i can't access a 'departments' property for each floor for instance"* why not? *"and i'd like to add data dynamically in these arrays."* that's possible with your current design.

Comment: `departments[0].department_name = 'some name'` or `departments[1].shelves.push({'someprop': 'somedata'})`

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding JavaScript object literals. They are completely different that structs in C. Structs are type declarations, JavaScript object literals are **actual objects**.

You should stop putting one key/value pair per object, and start making uniform objects that contain the same attributes.

When you write `[ { department_name: ... }, { shelves: ... } ]` you are defining an array that contains two unrelated objects, one containing a `department_name` property, and the other containing a `shelves` property. These objects know nothing about each other, or that they are contained in the same array.

Instead of this...

```
[
  {
     department_name: 'group_theory'
  },
  {
    shelves: [ 
    {
      shelf_name: 'letters_f_z'
    },
    {
      authors: ["Frobenius","Lagrange"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You should be writing:

```
{
  departments: [
    { # This entire object is a department. It has a name and shelves
      name: 'group_theory',
      shelves: [
        { # This entire object is a shelf. It has a name and authors.
          name: 'letters_f_z',
          authors: ["Frobenius","Lagrange"],
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To put it a different way, when you write this...

```
floors: [
     {floor_name:'Fermat'},
     {has_a_printing_machine:true},
     {departments:[...]}
]
```

You are not making an array of floors, you're making an array of three totally unrelated objects, one that contains a `floor_name` property, one that contains a `has_a_printing_machine` property, and one that contains a `departments` property. If you want all three objects to have all three properties, you need to declare them that way:

```
floors: [
     { name: 'floor_one', has_a_printing_machine: true, departments: [] },
     { name: 'floor_two', has_a_printing_machine: false, departments: [ ... ] },
     { name: 'floor_three', has_a_printing_machine: true, departments: [] },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You **almost** had it. Each floor is an entity on its own, with its properties. One of its properties is the list of departments, and each department is an entity itself too (again, with its own properties). And same with the shelves.

Each instance of an entity/struct/register is a dictionary, with its properties mapped as `key:value` pairs. So, for instance, a shelf could be:

```
var my_shelf = {
  shelf_name:'letters_f_z',
  authors: ["Frobenius","Lagrange"]
};
```

A department (with its shelves) may be:

```
{
    department_name:'group_theory',
    shelves:[
        {
            shelf_name:'letters_f_z',
            authors: ["Frobenius","Lagrange"]
        }, 
        {...}
    ]
}
```

I think at this point you can extrapolate this construction to the floors level, having an array of department registries as the value of the `departments` property.

Unfortunately, unlike TypeScript, which is a statically-typed superset of JavaScript, you can't enforce each register to actually have a certain set of properties. So you'll have to be extra-cautious when creating the instances so every property is initialized since its very beginning.